# Obtaining parameter errors with the basinhoppin method in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I use the basinhoppin method use in Python for global optimization. The result is named FittedParameters and is shown below:

```py
 fun: 495.41316629238105
 lowest_optimization_result:       fun: 495.41316629238105
 hess_inv: <4x4 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([ 2.89333002e-03,  8.60849241e+00, -4.03645117e-02, -2.78697598e-01])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
     nfev: 305
      nit: 44
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([5.37252873e+01, 1.00492918e-01, 1.09133525e+00, 1.80853365e-02])
                    message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
      minimization_failures: 0
                       nfev: 35770
                        nit: 100
                          x: array([5.37252873e+01, 1.00492918e-01, 1.09133525e+00, 1.80853365e-02])
```

$x$ is the array of parameters. I want to obtain the standard deviation of the parameters. For that, I think I need to calculate the square root of the diagonal of the inverse Hessian (is it?), so I recover the inverse of the Hessian using the function

```py
todense()
```

so the inverse Hessian is:

```py
fittedParameters.lowest_optimization_result.hess_inv.todense()
```

and the square root of its diagonal is:

```py
np.sqrt(np.diag(fittedParameters.lowest_optimization_result.hess_inv.todense()))
```

so the standard deviation gives me

```py
 array([5.44695331e+02, 5.16001372e-01, 4.38144991e+01, 2.93941432e+00])
```

which is impossible, because the fitted parameters are:

```py
array([5.37252873e+01, 1.00492918e-01, 1.09133525e+00, 1.80853365e-02])
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The hessian estimates from scipy optimizations aren't reliable (useful only for optimization). Instead, you should look at an exact method using the `autograd` library. See an example here: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/PyDataNY_2019_tutorial/blob/4a97ee6cd70cc6003cd13b880f4e8a4a80cde0c2/tutorial_notebooks/Part%205.ipynb

Comment: You saved my day, man. Do you know the reason why scipy optimizations are so bad at estimating hessians?

Comment: 1. They don't need to be exact. They just need to to get to the minimum. 2. Often they use finite difference methods, which have an error

Comment: One request from you: now that you have an answer, can you please self-answer this question? It makes QA discovery better for the site. (And my hint isn't sufficient for a answer)